# Not sure what type of Excel formula (SUM, SUMIF ect...) to use for my calculation, can you get me going in the right direction?

Tags: excel, formulas

In Excel Formulas there are so many different functions, that I am not sure which to use to get started. So if I were to give you an example could you point me in the right direction for learning what I need to do?

Ok so say you want 6 Apples (*D3*)
And you want 3 oranges (*D4*) (also buying 1-7 apples gets you 1 orange free so they only need to pay for 2 oranges but if they buy 8-14 they get 2 oranges free and if they buy 15-21 they would get 3 oranges free and so on and so on. multiples of 7 apples get you a free orange)
And 5 grapes (*D5*) (these are sold by the 3, so no matter if you buy 5 you get charged 2 because these are only sold in 3's)
And 4 Bananas (*D6*) (sold by the each)

So is there a way to formulate this and make it all be one price in *I3*? The prices are *D3=E11*, *D4=E12*, *D5=E13* and *D6=E14* but for some reason it will not pick anything up past *D4=E12*, the code stops changing colors when I am putting in the formula.

Not sure if this makes any sense so any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the rules right, I think your formula should be:

```
=D3*E11  +  MAX(0,D4-ROUNDUP(D3/7,0))*E12  +  ROUNDUP(D5/3,0)*E13  +  D6*E14
```

I've separated the blocks of calculations to make it easier to read.

I did assume the price you give for grapes (in E13) is for each set of 3 grapes.

(Edited - I just re-read your question - 1 apple gets 1 free orange, 8 apples gets 2 free oranges).

Comment: WOW thank you so much, I never expected for you to do the formula, it is greatly appreciated. I see now what I was doing wrong, this was the only piece I was missing, MAX(0,D4- for learning purposes and if you don't mind could you tell me what the MAX is for?

Comment: The `MAX` function returns the highest of the two arguments.  I used it to ensure the `D4-ROUNDUP(...)` didn't cause a negative orange cost (like if they bought 99 apples but only 1 orange).